How do I open the locked door in Fungal Wastes?
In the Fungal Wastes, there is a door that looks like this:
Apparently, it looks like this on the other side:
How do you open it? Is it even possible? There's no way to inspect it and get a hint. I don't see a way it could be locked behind an ability, as I have every single ability and upgrade (the photos aren't mine).

There is no way to unlock this door.
Quoting the wiki entry for City of Tears:

A sealed door above the entrance through the Pilgrim's Way appears to connect the City Storerooms lift to the Fungal Wastes. This can never be opened or interacted with during the game and remains permanently shut.

